# What is the difference between throttling network and network tuning?

Tags: tcp

What is the difference between throttling network and network tuning?

Doesn't both means to send with the maximum possible bandwidth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this article on Policing traffic versus Shaping traffic.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/quality-of-service-qos/qos-policing/19645-policevsshape.html

[image: Cisco: Policing vs. Shaping]

Policing (aka *throttling*) is done by dropping traffic when it exceeds the configured rate. Network Tuning (aka *shaping*, QoS, etc.) implements queues to hold traffic that exceeds configured rates. (this can include prioritization of different types/classes of traffic. eg. VoIP getting high priority than web browsing.)

Comment: I saw this diagram elsewhere (can't remember where) when I was trying to get a basic handle on QoS. Your explanation summarizes a lengthy and wandering document very well.